# FULLTEXT mysql return empty

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| imovel_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| user_id         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| img_dest        | varchar(111) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| data_imob       | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| finalidade_imob | varchar(51)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| status_imob     | varchar(51)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| tipo_imob       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| uf_imob         | varchar(51)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| cidade_imob     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| bairro_imob     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| rua_imob        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| vaga_imob       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| dorms_imob      | char(2)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| tamanho_imob    | varchar(222) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| valor_imob      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| titulo_imob     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| descricao_imob  | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| carac_imob      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

If I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM form_imovel LEFT JOIN (form_user) ON (form_user.user_id = form_imovel.user_id) WHERE MATCH(finalidade_imob,status_imob,tipo_imob,uf_imob,cidade_imob,bairro_imob,dorms_imob,valor_imob) AGAINST ('Comprar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Where `Comprar` is the value from `finalidade_imob` column, I have the right results, that work with all columns, except `uf_imob`column.

The `uf_imob`columns have values like: `SP`,`MG`,`RJ`.

If I try run the following query, it returns empty:

```
SELECT * FROM form_imovel LEFT JOIN (form_user) ON (form_user.user_id = form_imovel.user_id) WHERE MATCH(finalidade_imob,status_imob,tipo_imob,uf_imob,cidade_imob,bairro_imob,dorms_imob,valor_imob) AGAINST ('SP' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Even though that column has so many `SP` registers.

[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcdd33)

Comment: Perhaps it has more than 50%. See the manual.

Comment: sorry @Strawberry im new in mysql, 50% of what? can u indicate the point in the manual, pls?

Comment: The point where it says FULLTEXT

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @JorgeCampos Actually that's not the page I was thinking of.

Comment: @Strawberry i still not understand, i have more that 100 registers, with the possibles 3 values : `SP`, `MG`, `RJ`. `MG` have only two register is less than 50%, and not work too.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Well it does states "A natural language search interprets the search string as a phrase in natural human language (a phrase in free text). There are no special operators, with the exception of double quote (") characters. The stopword list applies. In addition, words that are present in **50%** or more of the rows are considered common and do not match."

Comment: @Jorge Campos as i say, `MG` have only two registers is more lass than 50%...

Comment: @Strawberry i made the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table and have a structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2273ef , can u help whit that? I never creat fiddle sql...

Comment: I cannot see any data.

Comment: @Strawberry i edit fiddle and insert some data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcdd33 tks for try help

Comment: Table 'db_9_dcdd33.form_user' doesn't exist

Comment: @Strawberry need remove on query left join...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcdd33/5 sorry

Comment: @Strawberry i think discovery the problem in `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len'; its like 4 i need 2 , you know answer me how change for 2 or oint me some question?